# Teradata-sqlalchemy not using database when given

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, teradata

I'm trying to connect to our internal Teradata database, using flask and sqlAlchemy along with a custom engine called sqlalchemy teradata. I put the database into the create_engine function likes so.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('teradata://username:pw@server_name/database')
```

I've setup my dialect just like in the tests

```
registry.register("tdalchemy", "sqlalchemy_teradata.dialect", "TeradataDialect")
```

I'm getting a.

```
DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (3807, u"[42S02] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Object 'table_name' does not exist
```

I can make raw sql queries just fine, I can also have alchemy do a query I construct and it pulls the data. I'm not sure what all is preventing things from working properly at all. When I test a similar call but looking at a database in an psql server it works just fine and pulls from that db without issue.

Also the pypi page says there is supposed to be an test/orm_test.py but it doesn't seem to have it.